# Yii2 REST API Overlapping rate limits

Tags: php, api, rest, yii2

In Yii2 is it possible to have overlapping REST API rate limits?  For example, 1 request per second AND 1000 requests per day (24 hour period)?  If so, how would I do this?

Comment: Have you looked over \yii\filters\RateLimiter and \yii\filters\RateLimitInterface? Extending those and adding your business logic should get you want you want.

Comment: Thanks.  Any code suggestions?

Comment: Anyone else have any suggestions or recommendations on how to do this?

Comment: it's possible by add column to user table and update with ur code.